# Question About DXA implementation?

Tags: templating, dxa

I have just setup DXA sample website with Oracle database. but when I am trying to browse pages, I am getting all pages without css.

on further investigation, I found that css file url shows version info "/system/v0.82/assets/css/main.css" and the broker database url is without version info "/system/assets/css/main.css".

How can i resolve this issue?

Where can I get the DXA Dafault Template classes visual studio project?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is correct. The version number is not added in database along with the resources. It is added only when the resources are serialized to the file system in /system/{version}/resources format.
The version number is appended from the HTML Design Configuration component.

I believe this design is used to avoid caching issues.
(when you make any changes in the assets, update the HTML Design Configuration component with next version number and publish the 'Publish settings' page.  This way the the browser is deceived to look for new content rather than the cached content.)

So cross check the views if they are written to read this version number.

The DXA project is uploaded by Bart at : [VS Templates Project](https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/tree/master/content-management)